# Convertir un String a Array[Int] y viceversa

Tags: swift3, swift4

Help me please!

> **STRING** *to* **ARRAY[Int]**

**input :** `var str = "4869"`

**output:** `var num:[Int] = [4,8,6,9]`

---

> **ARRAY[Int]** *to* **STRING**

**input :** `var num2:[Int] = [5,8,9,6]`

**output:** `var str2 = "5896"`

Answer (score 1):

Version corta sin explicación:

```
import UIKit

let str = "24234k234hj234"
var digits = str.flatMap({Int(String($0))})

print(digits)
```

imprime

```
[2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]
```

al reves

```
let numbers= [1,2,3] 
let text = numbers.map({String($0)}).joined()
```

imprime

```
"123"
```

Explicación

Un string se puede interpretar como un arreglo de caracteres, por lo que recorrerlo.

```
let str = "123456"
for char in str {

}
```

Ahora, cada elemento es de tipo *character*, por lo que tienes que castearlo, una forma podrías ser:

```
Int(char)
```

Pero *Int* no tiene un constructor con tipo *character*, así que antes tendrías que pasar es *chracter* a *string*

String(char)

Luego pasarlo a *Int*

Int(String(char))

Eso sí, este constructor devuelve un *optional* por lo que tendrías que hacer un unwrapping.

Int(String(char))!

Esto, *forced unwrapping* no es recomendable, por lo que podrías ponerlo dentro de un condicional, así te aseguras de solo tomar los número, acá un ejemplo completo

```
import UIKit

let str = "123123"
var digits: [Int] = []

for char in str {
    if let digit = Int(String(char)) {
        digits.append(digit)
    }
}

print(digits)
```

en este caso imprime

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

otro ejemplo, con letras entremedio

```
let str = "24234k234hj234"
...
print(str)
```

imprime

```
[2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]
```

map es una function que te permite aplicar un acción a cada elemento del arreglo, flatMap ignora los nulos y entrega la versión no 
*optional*

joined junta los elementos de un arreglo.